# Google Maps fitBounds not working on map inside of modal

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map within a modal that I am attempting to call fitBounds on, based on a a set of points. The value of the points will vary depending on database values, but I've set the values below for simplification.

When the map is placed outside the modal, it works fine. Once inside the modal however, the fitBounds call always zooms out too far.

I thought it might be related to the modal not being visible, but I've put the function inside of the modal callback and that didn't seem to help.

The site is using Laravel 5.8.38.

My page content:

```
<head>
    <!-- CSS Includes - Bootstrap 4.4.1 -->
    {{ Html::style('css/app.css') }}
</head>

<body>

    <div class="content">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map_modal">View Map</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="map_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id="map" style="margin: 15px; height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript Includes - jQuery 3.4.1 -->
    {{ Html::script('js/app.js') }}

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map;

        $('#map_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            showMap();
        });

        function showMap() {
            // points a and b will vary depending on database values and which elements the user interacts with
            var a = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.7760588,-74.2972913),
                map: map,
                label: "A"
            });
            var b = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.9350477,-74.024461),
                map: map,
                label: "A"
            });
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            bounds.extend(a.getPosition());
            bounds.extend(b.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: 41.798057, lng: -73.973488},
                zoom: 8
            });
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</body>
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. And btw. `show.bs.modal` is not the callback for when the modal is show**n**.

Comment: what is the proper callback then?

Comment: I put that `n` in bold in my previous comment... `shown.bs.modal` is the event if my memory is good enough. That's still not a [mcve] btw. What version of bootstrap are you using? How/where are you calling the maps API? etc. You should provide all that in a stack snippet, that's just easier for everyone.

Comment: And why do you need to create the markers and fit the bounds *when* the modal is shown? Can you not do it in the map init?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

```
        $('#request_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            showMap();
        });
```

needed to be changed to

```
        $('#request_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            showMap();
        });
```